# Converting UIView with clear background color into a UIImage adds white background color to image generated

Tags: swift

I'm trying to convert a view on my scene to a UIImage to be used in snapchats API for stickers. When the image is generated from the view, all is right except for the white background. I do not want a background.

I have tried converting the image to jpeg and checked that the background is actually clear.

```
    let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: contentView.bounds.size)        
    let image = renderer.image { ctx in
        contentView.drawHierarchy(in: contentView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    }
    let imageData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)!




    let stickerImage = UIImage(data:imageData,scale:1.0)!
    //let stickerImage = /* Prepare a sticker image */
    let sticker = SCSDKSnapSticker(stickerImage: stickerImage)
    /* Alternatively, use a URL instead */
    // let sticker = SCSDKSnapSticker(stickerUrl: stickerImageUrl, isAnimated: false)

    /* Modeling a Snap using SCSDKNoSnapContent */
    let snap = SCSDKNoSnapContent()
    snap.sticker = sticker /* Optional */
    snap.caption = "Snap on Snapchat!" /* Optional */
    snap.attachmentUrl = "https://www.snapchat.com"
    view.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    snapAPI.startSending(snap) { [weak self] (error: Error?) in
        self?.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        // Handle response
    }
```

Compiles and runs, just has a white background to the UIView where it should be clear

Comment: Why do you convert `image` (`UIImage`) to JPEG data just so you can create a new `UIImage` from the JPEG data? At least use PNG data which actually supports transparency and is a much more suitable format for a screenshot.

Comment: Did you get this working all the way through thee share to Snapchat? I'm trying to do a very similar thing and it seems to maintain transparency through every step until Snapchat opens it and then it has a white background. If I share a URL to the exact same image hosted somewhere on the web, Snapchat will load it with transparency... but not from a local file.

Comment: @MaxSchmeling I had to update the snapkit pod, it was fixed in the recent update

Comment: @ClayLoneman Yes! Sorry, I should have followed up here... I had filed an issue with them and they let me know the update was coming. The latest definitely fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `SCSDK` but this is the extension I use for turning UIViews into images, and it works fine for transparent backgrounds. Assuming you aren't set on using that library, you could try this method.

```
extension UIImage {

    /// Creates a UIImage 'snapshot' of a UIView.
    convenience init(from view: UIView) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.isOpaque, 0.0)
        view.drawHierarchy(in: view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.init(cgImage: (image?.cgImage)!)
    }

}
```

Call with:

```
let image = UIImage(from: myView)
```

Let me know if that works for you.

Comment: this worked thank you! I believe the .isOpaque declaration fixed my issue.